# Rails elsif block for Rails.env

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to redirect user depends on environment. URLs for staging and production are in rails credentials, to avoid specs error I had to add `new_session_path(resource_name)` when environment is not staging or production. I've got below elsif block:

```
    protected

    def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name)
      if Rails.env.staging?
        Rails.application.credentials.confirmation_account_url_staging
      elsif Rails.env.production?
        Rails.application.credentials.confirmation_account_url_production
      else
        new_session_path(resource_name)
      end
    end
```

I don't know if this is a good approach to use elsif block in that case, is there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

you can put it in a `.env` file so for each environment you put the suitable url

so when you do `ENV[CONFIRMATION_ACCOUNT_URL]` you will get the correct url depending on the environment of the running app.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `.env` file for each enviroment likely `.env.production` and `.env.staging` or `.env.development`. Then put your variable to each `.env` file.
Rails will check current enviroment to get your `.env` variable.